# Excel SUMPRODUCT with OR and multiple criteria in { }

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like with sumproduct to sum where:

```
name = {"john","an","hui","james"}
OR
Number= {"one","two","five","six","ten"}
SUM
table1[Salary]


=SUMPRODUCT(((table1[Name] = {"john","an","hui","james"})+(table1[Number]= {"one","two","five","six","ten"}))*(table1[Salary]))
```

But I am getting the error message #N/A could you please help with the function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`=SUMPRODUCT(GESTEP(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Name],{"john","an","hui","james"},0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Number],{"one","two","five","six","ten"},0)),1),Table1[Salary])`

Comment: thank you, I am having a problem understanding it fully, but please how would you add one more argument to this OR table1[house],{"big","small"}

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(GESTEP(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Name],{"john","an","hui","james"},0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[Number],{"one","two","five","six","ten"},0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[house],{"big","small"},0)),1),Table1[Salary])`. Repeat the `ISNUMBER/MATCH` construction for each additional column you wish to interrogate as part of your OR logic.